# Question about pressure, surface area and force in tire

Tags: homework-and-exercises, pressure

Assuming that the temperature in the tire suddenly rises.
My question is: would that cause the **contact** surface area between the tires and the floor increase, decrease, or stay the same?
(given that the volume of air in the tires is a **constant** and cannot be changed)
Also, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A perfect circle is the shape that contains the maximum area within, given a fixed perimeter length.

The contact area with the floor will decrease because the pressure inside the tire will rise (assuming the gas inside expands when hot). Since a perfect cylinder, or circular outer rim, is the shape which maximizes the volume contained inside of that fixed perimeter, the tire will tend toward the perfect circular shape to equalize the pressure inside of the tire. That tendency will shorten the length of the arc cord forming the flat on the bottom, and reduce the floor surface contact.

Answer (score -1):

The contact area is that surface needed to carry the load (about 1/4 of the weight of the car for a particular tire). Force = pressure times area.

If the total amount of air in the tire is unchanged, and the volume of air cannot change, then the ideal gas law tells us that in response to an increase in temperature, the pressure in the tire must increase.

Can you figure it out now?

Comment: I realized the force of air in the tire also increase, but is it negligible?

Answer (score -1):

Like Entrepreneur posted as an answer adding pressure to the tire will decrease the deformation caused by contact with the ground.

If this is a real-world question though the increase in temperature will be reflected in the rubber of the tire. A hot tire is softer and more flexible, this will cause the tire to balloon out in any direction the steel raidial webbing allows. Your contact patch should increase in size because the thick / stiff sidewall is softer and will carry less load.

In most modern tires the sidewall does carry a significant part of the load, this is why low tire pressure leads to a blow-out. Low pressure causes the sidewall to sag and flex more as the tire rotates this flexing actually builds up more heat. The heat expands the air inside the tire but the hot and soft sidewall cannot support the vehicle so the tire continues to sag and flex. More heat builds up and pressure can actually increase inside the tire until the flexing causes failure in the sidewall or tread and a blow-out happens.

Drew K